# Integrar postman test con gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, postman, gitlab-ci

hay alguna forma de integrar estos 2 servicios , ya que veo que podría usar travis con postman , pero no quiero prescindir del ci y cd de gitlab.

Estoy tratando de usar los runners de gitlab junto con la api de postman , sin embargo siento que estoy añadiendo complejidad extra la cual me gustaría disminuir.

Comment: Puedes utilizar seguro el modo Shell del Runner y así lanzas el postman en la fase que te parezca (supongo que tendrás algún modo de lanzarlo desde la shell, no??)

Comment: Claro que es posible, yo considero a postman como una herramienta y sinceramente usaría otra cosa como restassured o alguna solución más programática